# MySQL Complex Queries

Tags: mysql

Hey I've been killing myself trying to figure out how to do these queries. Can someone help me out.
These are the tables I have currently.

BOOKING

HOTEL_NO
GUEST_NO
DATE_FROM 
DATE_TO
ROOM_NO

GUEST

GUEST_NO
GUEST_NAME
CITY
ADDRESS
ZIP_CODE

HOTEL

HOTEL_NO
HOTEL_NAME
CITY
ADDRESS
ZIP_CODE
STAR

ROOM

ROOM_NO
HOTEL_NO
ROOM_TYPE 
PRICE

And these are the queries I need to do.

-List the guests that have all their bookings (past and present) in the same hotel.

-Create a view VIP-Guest that lists guests who have reservations for only 4 star hotels or
4 star hotels

-Among the VIPs find the guest with the largest total stay (in term of number of days).
Express this as a query with the view and without the view

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What, exactly, is your problem? Don't say "I don't know how to do it" - [so] is __not__ a free coding service.

Comment: This is what i tried for the first question.

Comment: SELECT G.GUEST_NAME, COUNT(B.HOTEL_NO)
FROM GUEST G, BOOKING B
WHERE G.GUEST_NO = B.GUEST_NO
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;     .... This works but I dont know why it doesnt give me what I want.

Comment: Instead of adding a comment, edit your original post and put the queries you have tested in there that show the efforts you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

this should get you started.  to post on stackoverflow, you need to come with specific questions or errors or problems.  like for the query you posted in the comments up top.... that could be a question in itself:  *"I have these tables, this one specific goal (question/result set), and I tried this query... it gives me this result or it gives me this error."*

```
BOOKING:  HOTEL_NO, GUEST_NO, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, ROOM_NO

GUEST:    GUEST_NO, GUEST_NAME, CITY, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE

HOTEL:    HOTEL_NO, HOTEL_NAME, CITY, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE, STAR

ROOM:     ROOM_NO, HOTEL_NO, ROOM_TYPE, PRICE
```

all guests and bookings...

```
   -- all guests:  select * from guest;
   -- all bookings:  select * from booking; 

   select   * 
   from     guest
            join booking on guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no;

   -- which is the same as... 

   select   * 
   from     guest, booking 
   where    guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no;

   -- and... your comments query was missing a group by clause

   select   guest_no, guest_name, count(*) as booking_count
   from     guest
            join booking on guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no
   group    by guest_no, guest_name; 

   select   guest_no, guest_name, count(distinct hotel_no) as hotel_count
   from     guest
            join booking on guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no
   group    by guest_no, guest_name 
   having   count(distinct hotel_no) = 1;
```

and I `count(distinct hotel_no)` because... they might have 3 bookings at Hotel A and 1 at Hotel B.  The basic join would give me 4 rows for that person.  I don't care how many bookings.  I care how many hotels.  So I want to count the distinct occurrences of `hotel_no` per person (there's that group by) instead of every row.

guests by their stars...

```
   -- so we have to get guest and hotel joined.  bc hotel has stars.  
   -- booking has hotel_no.  so... we can use that last query and 
   -- join in HOTEL to get the star information.  in the WHERE you 
   -- will want to put your filter for the number of stars that you
   -- are looking for =4 or >=4 or something like that.
   -- you might want to check out DISTINCT to get just a list of names 
   -- instead of a row for each booking.
```

number of days they stayed...

```
   -- use the second query.  
   -- datediff(date_to, date_from) as days_stay gives you the length of stay  
   -- i don't know what the view is. 
   -- to get the top length could go two ways... either ORDER BY and LIMIT if there is 
   -- only one person with the top length (let's say 10 days).  if there are many people
   -- who have stayed 10 days, you'll need to do a MAX on the days_stay and either join 
   -- that in or use it in the WHERE as a nested select.
```

---

this assumes there is a single highest length of stay.  only one person stayed 10 days.

```
SELECT  guest_no, guest_name, datediff(date_to, date_from) days_stayed

FROM    vip_guest 

        join booking on vip_guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no 

order   by datediff(date_to, date_from) desc
limit   1,1
```

this should work for many... (i'm not testing these... just kind of looking at it)

```
SELECT  distinct guest_no, guest_name, datediff(date_to, date_from) max_stay

FROM    vip_guest

        join booking on vip_guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no 

where   datediff(date_to, date_from) = (
                     select max(datediff(date_to, date_from)) as days_stayed 
                     from   booking )
```

the nested query gets the maximum stay length of everyone.  vip_guest and bookings joined together give us guest and date imfo.  we will get all bookings for every vip_guest.  so we want to filter it down to where stay lengths == the max stay length.  in case a person had multiple 10 day stays (my arbitrary max stay length)... use distinct.

now... thats a good point about the nested query.  i don't know what is in your view.  it is possible none of the max vip guests had a stay as long as the max stay length.  in that case, this query would return nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped. I'm having some trouble with the last one still. This is the query I have.                 SELECT *
FROM VIP_GUEST V
WHERE EXISTS(
 SELECT B.GUEST_NO, DATEDIFF(B.DATE_TO, B.DATE_FROM) AS DAYS_STAYED
 FROM BOOKING B
 WHERE V.GUEST_NO = B.GUEST_NO
    AND DAYS_STAYED = MAX(DAYS_STAYED);
 );                                                              But I can't figure out how to properly used days_stayed.

Comment: got it! figured it out

Comment: @richard - awesome.  there are a lot of different ways to write that query, btw.  i'm not sure what you've been learning in class. pick what is most relevant to the material covered.